# Wanted: The [finalizer] to [finalize] [finalization]

Tags: support, synonym-request

The tags [finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalize) and [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer) have the exact same Wiki and appear to serve the same purpose.

As of time of this posting:
[finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalize) has 0 followers and a tag count of 125, 20 asked this year.
[finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer) has 3 followers and a tag count of 283, 42 asked this year.
 
[finalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalization) has 0 followers and a tag count of 30, 3 asked this year, no wiki.

Looking through questions in these tags, subjects seem similar and it appears they could be (and often are) used interchangeably.

I don't have the rep needed, but this looks like a good case for tag-synonyms.
Given the followers and the higher volume of use, I would suggest [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer) be the master.

Comment: @MrLister - why would I edit "finally" into the title?  As far as I can see, there's no indication this tag would relate to the others.  From looking at the questions, it looks like it's mostly used to relate to the "finally" block of the "try-catch-finally" construct - but I just glanced at a few questions, so could have other uses - given that there is no wiki filled out for it to provide usage guidelines ;)

Comment: Considering the amount of followers I wonder if anybody will notice if we just burn the tags...

Comment: Did someone mention tagless final representations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the tag wikis histories, I'd say that [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer) probably existed first:

- Wiki for [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer) was [created by Justin Oct 18 '11 at 15:01](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7809401/revisions)
- Wiki for [finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalize) was [created by Community Oct 30 '13 at 5:40](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19674679/revisions)

Both tag wikis got a very similar wiki that seems to be geared more toward [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer).  It's also a (IMO) much better tag since it refers to the programming concept instead of a specific method name.  So I think that [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer) should be the main tag and the other ones should point to it.